# How to view DOM of a URL programmatically after it was interpreted by browser?

Tags: javascript, html, curl, dom, inspector

On a web page, viewing the **View Source** is different from what is shown in **Elements** using the chrome inspector/developer tools. I believe this is because it is the result after the browser has interpreted it with changes made by JavaScript that cannot be seen simply from the HTML source.

Is there any way I can simply use `curl` to retrieve the DOM ***after*** it has been interpreted by the browser? Or would this require a 3rd party tool / command line headless browser?

Comment: *Or would this require a 3rd party tool / command line headless browser?* That's right - the HTML you want after the change isn't visible anywhere until after the Javascript has run

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance . Do you have any recommendations for a command line tool that can be used to retrieve this DOM after it has been interpreted by the browser?

Comment: I don't have experience with that sort of thing, but I'm sure *something* exists that can do that. (maybe Puppeteer?)

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but it's explicitly off-topic to ask for  recommendations for tools or libraries. (But if you remove that last question, it just might be ok.)

Comment: `Curl` is a tool that access web content through `http` protocol, it will only get the `text/html` output of an `URL`. Curl won't run any *Javascript or Css*, you will always get the *original/untransformed* result. You will have to use tool that mimic browser to get final result.